# Selecting different columns of joined tables based on certain criteria

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, select, sql-server-2014

I wanted to retrieve single rows of two columns based on a certain criteria after joining multiple tables. To explain it with example, I've this:

```
SELECT c.column1, c.column2, d.column3, d.column4 
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN table3 c ON b.tabid = c.tabid
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON c.pmid=d.pmid 
WHERE a.id = @id
```

In the case column1 and column2 are not NULL, I want two of them be retrieved as

```
SELECT c.column1, c.column2 
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN table3 c ON b.tabid = c.tabid
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON c.pmid=d.pmid 
WHERE a.id = @id
```

Otherwise, I would like to have

```
SELECT d.column3, d.column4
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN table3 c ON b.tabid = c.tabid
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON c.pmid=d.pmid 
WHERE a.id = @id
```

I would use IF clause with COUNT function to first see individually whether the columns are null or not, then would use a plain SELECT statement to retrieve. But it will be a triple effort of reading from the same table 3 times (to check counts of each column is > 0 or not; in the case both are true, to select from those columns). I believe it can be enhanced better.

I was also considering to use two separate common table expressions to use with CASE. But ended up with syntactical error.

Any guidance will be appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? Can you use `IsNull()` or `COALESCE()` functions?

Comment: SQL 2014. I could use that. But I have to check that both columns are not NULL.

Comment: If 1 of them is null then what?

Comment: If one of c.column1, c.column2 is null, I will take d.column3, d.column3.

Comment: Make it easy to assist: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 2):

You can use a case statement do determine which columns are outputted from the query. If both are null, output columns 3 and 4 and if not output columns 1 and 2. You may need to change which are outputted.

```
SELECT 
case when isnull(c.column1,'') = '' and isnull(c.column2,'') = '' 
then c.column1 + c.column2 else c.column3 + c.column4 end as 'Column'
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN table3 c ON b.tabid = c.tabid
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON c.pmid=d.pmid 
WHERE a.id = @id
```

For the above answer, if any of the columns in output may be null, you will need to wrap each columns in the output in an isnull statement to avoid nulling the value of both columns.

If you want two separate column outputs, use two case statements:

```
SELECT 
case when isnull(c.column1,'') = '' and isnull(c.column2,'') = '' 
then c.column1  else c.column3  end as 'Column1',
case when isnull(c.column1,'') = '' and isnull(c.column2,'') = '' 
then c.column2 else c.column4 end as 'Column2'
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN table3 c ON b.tabid = c.tabid
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON c.pmid=d.pmid 
WHERE a.id = @id
```

You may need to adjust the case statement and I think there are better ways in SQL 2014 (I am stuck in SQL 2018 R2 mode right now).

Comment: I think OP wanted separate columns, not combined columns.

Comment: I originally answered as two columns then updated to one after rereading.. I'll update to handle both scenarios.

Comment: The columns should be retrieved separately. Not concatenated.

Comment: @kenean, I adjusted to answer both concatenated and separate column returns.

Comment: I think this should be working. But ISNULL can still be avoided simply using a CASE statement with IS NOT NULL. Thanks.

Comment: @kenean your right that "is null" should suffice. I get into the habit of using isnull(,....) because of concatenation issues I've had in the past.

Answer (score 1):

I think this gives what you want:

```
select 
  case when c.column1 is null or c.column2 is null then d.column3 else c.column1 end,
  case when c.column1 is null or c.column2 is null then d.column4 else c.column2 end
FROM table1 a 
JOIN table2 b ON a.id=b.id 
JOIN table3 c ON b.tabid = c.tabid
LEFT JOIN table4 d ON c.pmid=d.pmid 
WHERE a.id = @id
```

It is the same condition checked twice.

Comment: @WEI_DBA it should be an "and" not an "or" since both columns should be null

Comment: @forpas Corrected! My bad. Thanks.

Comment: @SteveB, Read in the comments the OP's answer to fopas' question.